# Prove that two maximal $k$-connected sub-graphs of a graph $G$ have at most $k-1$ common vertices.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Assume that the two sub-graphs $A$ and $B$ of graph $G$ such that $A \neq B$.

A maximal $k$-connected sub-graph will not be a "proper" sub-graph for any other $k$-connected sub-graph. Here - $k$ is the size of the minimal vertex cut.

How do I prove this by contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the two maximal $k$-connected subgraphs share $k$ vertices. Deleting any $k-1$ vertices across the two subgraphs leaves both subgraphs connected *and* must leave at least one common vertex, so the union of subgraphs remains connected after deleting any $k-1$ vertices – it is $k$-connected and strictly larger than both original subgraphs, a contradiction. Hence the statement is proved.

Comment: Bravo! Thanks for framing it so well.